# Excel- transpose columns with vlookup grouped by ID and date

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup, transpose

In Excel 2016 on Windows 10, I have a workbook with several columns. The column I’m interested in is the date. I want to pull those dates into another workbook with a vlookup function. I am using the ID as the reference between the two workbooks.

```
**ID**   **Date**
100      11/13/2017
100      12/1/2017
100      1/20/2018
200      10/20/2014
200      11/12/2014
200      12/14/2014
200      1/10/2015
300      8/9/2015
300      9/10/2015
300      10/12/2015
```

The dates are in Excel as Date format. 
I would like this transposed to

```
**ID** 

100 11/13/2017 12/1/2017 1/20/2018 
200 10/20/2014 11/12/2014 12/14/2014 1/10/2015
300 8/9/2015 9/10/2015 10/12/2015
```

in the new workbook. There can be between 1 and 12 dates for each ID. I would prefer they be ordered chronologically, but order of the dates isn’t as important to me as their orientation.

I thought just now I could do this with a pivot table, but it doesn’t give the date, just a summary of one kind or another and I don’t know how to remove the spaces.
EDIT:The data are grouped and sorted by the ID.

Comment: How much data do you have?  Is the data ALWAYS sorted on ID like your example?  If not sorted, it will require some array type formulas and too many of these will cause the calculations to run slow and possibly even crash excel.

Comment: Use Power Query and group by ID.  Plenty of examples. Post back if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Power Query and I didn't have time to learn it. I don't know VBA and I'm not very advanced with other Excel functions, but I figured out a very basic way to make the transposition. I suppose one could make a macro with this, but I didn't get that far. I tried to get screen shots to go with the steps. Here is a view of some starting data:

[image: one column:ID, second column:dates(text format)]

I use Insert tab on the Ribbon to insert a Pivot Table. In the pivot table, activated ID and Date. Add ID to the Rows section, Date to the Columns section, and Date again to the Values section.

[image: pivot table with ID and Date for fields. the ID is in rows section, Date is in the columns section, and Values section is set to Sum of Date]

I copy the values from the pivot table, leaving off the Total (or Sum or whatever it's called) row and column, to a new blank worksheet.

[image: table of copy of values arranged as in pivot table]

I highlight the rows and columns of that cover the dates I want to collapse to rows, leaving off the left-most column with the IDs and the top row, which is a sort of header row of dates.
On the Home tab of Ribbon, I use the Find and Select menu to select "Go to Special", which opens a new window with a menu. Note that you can also use F5 to get a slightly different Find window and there, go to bottom left and select "Special"(no screen shot of that option this time).

[image: find and select menu "go to special" highlighted]

In the "Go to Special" window menu, select the "Blanks" option.

[image: "go to special" menu with radial button selecting "blanks"]

This will highlight all the empty cells in the table I selected just a moment ago.

[image: table showing all blank cells within working range selected]

I RIGHT click on one of **blank** cells for the context menu and select Delete. Once Delete selected, I get another menus that asks how to handle left over cells. I select "Shift cells left".

[image: delete menu with "move cells left" selected]

The empty cells in front of and between the cells with date values are deleted and all of the dates slide in flush to the left, next to the corresponding ID fields. In the screen shot, I hadn't removed the selection yet, but that's cosmetic at this point. The dates that had been arranged in a column with multiple instances of the ID they correspond to are now arranged in rows with one instance of the ID and the dates growing out to the right. The dates are currently formatted as text in the screen shot. Just need to change that by selecting the dates and changing the format to Short Date.

[image: all date values are collapsed to left.]